# Split Panda Columns into Multiple Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple columns which I'd like to merge into a single one. The other difficulty is that an Animal (Eg. Dog) can have multiple codes (so string concat won't work).

I've tried pivot, stack, unstack but the multiple **values** columns is making this difficult for me to comprehend.

Original DataFrame:

| Animal | Code_X | Code_Y | Code_Z | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | 111 |  |  | $3 | $3 | $3 |
| Dog |  | 222 | 333 | $4 | $4 | $4 |
| Mouse |  | 444 |  | $5 | $5 | $5 |
| Fox | 555 | 666 |  | $6 | $6 | $6 |

Desired Dataframe:

| Animal | Code | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | 111 | $3 | $3 | $3 |
| Dog | 222 | $4 | $4 | $4 |
| Dog | 333 | $4 | $4 | $4 |
| Mouse | 444 | $5 | $5 | $5 |
| Fox | 555 | $6 | $6 | $6 |
| Fox | 666 | $6 | $6 | $6 |

Is there a way to do this in one swoop? My last result is creating a new dataframe with desired headers and using `df.append()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df.melt(['Animal', 'Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'], value_name='Code')\
  .dropna(subset=['Code'])\
  .drop('variable', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Animal Value1 Value2 Value3   Code
0    Cat     $3     $3     $3  111.0
3    Fox     $6     $6     $6  555.0
5    Dog     $4     $4     $4  222.0
6  Mouse     $5     $5     $5  444.0
7    Fox     $6     $6     $6  666.0
9    Dog     $4     $4     $4  333.0
```

Comment: So it was melt! Thank you

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that is one way to do it.  You're welcome.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.